# Using HTML::FormFu, how do you change a field value *after* processing so that it appears modified in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer, html-formfu

For example, if I process a form:

```
my $form_input = { input_data => '123' };
$form->process($form_input);
```

Then I want to alter the value of 'input_data':

```
my $clearme = $form->get_field('input_data');
$clearme->value("546"); # doesn't seem to work
```

..Before pushing the form object to TT:

```
template 'index' => { form => $form }; # using Dancer
```

'input_data' seems to retain it's original value (123).  Any hints on what I'm doing wrong, or what I should be doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the documentation and doing some testing, I think you want

```
$form->add_valid(input_data => '546');
```

Comment: huzzah, ikegami wins this round.  $form->add_valid() is the way to go. The naming convention in HTML::FormFu always throws me off :(  I've been looking for something along the lines of "clear", "reset", "delete", "unset" or just "value".. never would I think "add_valid" would allow me to *change* the value of an existing element.